# Pulling Higher Quality Google Images from Strings

Tags: javascript, api

I built this script that based on any query, it pulls the first google image that it finds through the use of a google customer search api. It works correctly, but it tends to pull low quality images. How can I augment this code such that it pulls an image that has a certain number of pixels or is more high quality?

My code can be found here: https://codepen.io/Julienw2/pen/OJoaMEO

I believe maybe something could be adjusted in this section, but I don't really know:

```js
function getImageUrl(searchTerm, callback, errorCallback) {
    // Google image search - 100 searches per day.
    // https://developers.google.com/image-search/
    // var searchUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images' +
    //   '?v=1.0&q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
    var searchUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1' +
      '?key=' + key + '&cx=' + cx + '&searchType=image&q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
  
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', searchUrl);
    // The Google image search API responds with JSON, so let Chrome parse it.
    x.responseType = 'json';
    x.onload = function() {
      // Parse and process the response from Google Image Search.
      var response = x.response;
      if (!response || !response.items || response.items.length === 0) {
        errorCallback('No response from Google Image search!');
        return;
      }
      var firstResult = response.items[0];
      // Take the thumbnail instead of the full image to get an approximately
      // consistent image size.
      var imageUrl = firstResult.image.thumbnailLink;
      var width = parseInt(firstResult.image.thumbnailWidth);
      var height = parseInt(firstResult.image.thumbnailHeight);
      console.assert(
          typeof imageUrl == 'string' && !isNaN(width) && !isNaN(height),
          'Unexpected respose from the Google Image Search API!');
      callback(imageUrl, width, height, searchTerm);
    };
    x.onerror = function() {
      errorCallback('Network error.');
    };
    x.send();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the Custom Search [docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list), it doesn't look like you can truly target images based on pixel density. There is the `imgSize` query parameter, however. You could include `imgSize=large` in your searchUrl to search for only large images, which usually tend to be higher quality.

You can find more information here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS.img_size

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is super helpful. How can I rewrite that line to include imgSize=large?

Comment: Try this:    
    
 `var searchUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1' +
      '?key=' + key + '&cx=' + cx + '&imgSize=large&searchType=image&q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);`    
    
You can also use template literals, which I find a bit easier to read:  
    
var searchUrl = ` `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${key}&cx=${cx}&imgSize=large&searchType=image&q=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`;`    
    
More information on that here:     
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals